# How to hide option value in a select tag?

Tags: asp.net

I have this code below:

```
<select size="1" name="sel1">
    <option value="c1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="c2">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="c3">Choice 3</option>
    <option value="c4">Choice 4</option>
</select>
```

Then what I want to happen, is to hide for example the 1st option in a method (for example below) in the .aspx.cs file.  How to do that?

```
protected void RptFaqsAnswer_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e){
     // codes here...
}
```

Thanks

RJ

Comment: Please accept some of your previous answers. Read the [faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to see how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "hiding" an option? Hide from whom?

Comment: like I need to hide a certain option from the user at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `runat=server` to make the code-behind aware of the HTML markup.  There are two approaches you could take.

**Approach #1** *Make the `select` an HTML server control*.

This will hide the option on the client side (ie, it still renders the HTML, just tells the browser not to display it).

```
<select runat="server" id="myselect">
    <option value="c1">Choice 1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then you can modify the options however you like, eg:

```
myselect.Items[0].Attributes.Add("display", "none");
```

**Approach #2** *Make the `option` elements server controls*.

This will not render the option to the client at all.

```
<select>
    <option value="c1" runat="server" id="option1">Choice 1</option>
</select>
```

And set `Visible` to false in the code behind:

```
option1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I need to add my code in a method with this parameter (object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)

in the method body, i need to get the id of that option.

var optionID = e.Item.FindControl("option1").ClientID;

but my problem now, I cannot find the optionID.Visible attribute. I guess i still need to parse the optionID object to "option" object. how to do that?

thanks

Comment: @user1120260 that's a completely different question -- I'd suggest creating a new question or revising this one.  The short answer, though, is that you need to cast it as an *HtmlGenericControl*:  **(e.Item.FindControl("option1") as HtmlGenericControl).Visible = false**.  (**Note** for this to work, you'll also have to add **runat="server" to the *option* tag.)

Comment: What if take the Approach #1. var optionID = e.Item.FindControl("myselect").ClientID as HtmlGenericControl will still work? I tried this one, but its not working.

Comment: @user1120260 You could -- but it should be like this:  **(e.Item.FindControl("myselect") as HtmlSelect).Items[0].Attributes.Add("display", "none");**

Comment: @user1120260 Actually, I'm not sure this will work.  Is *myselect* a child of the repeater?  The ID might not be "myselect", it could be something else.

Comment: yes, it's a child of the repeater... i tried to use this one but I am getting an error.... this is the code that I have... (e.Item.FindControl("myselect").ClientID as HtmlSelect).Items[3].Attributes.Add("display", "none");